# "A formidable figure she was too, in her belted smock and green breeches" Is this sentence a relative clause?

Tags: relative-clauses, inversion

> A formidable figure she was too, in her belted smock and green breeches

Is this sentence a relative clause ?

like  'A formidable figure (which) she was too'

Comment: She was a formidable figure, too.  It's an inversion, used for emphasis.  The verbs argument appears before the subject.

Comment: but the verbs argument in that sentence is 'was'.   according to your explanation, it has to be like this : A formidable figure was she too.   isn't it??

Comment: Regardless of word order, "was" isn't the argument; it's the verb.  "She" is the subject, "was" is the verb, "a formidable figure" is the argument -- here, a subject complement.  "A formidable figure was she" is also (possibly) an inversion, but then it's difficult to say whether "a formidable figure" is the argument in an unusual place, rather than the subject in canonical position.  Dahl's sentence doesn't have that ambiguity.  The order there is argument, then subject, then verb.